# How can I invoke a Processing method from outside a Processing sketch?

Tags: java, processing

I want to have a method `invokeProcessingMethod(String name, Object... args)` that invokes a method from Processing and returns any value that may result.

I already have a method `invokeMethod(String name, Object...args)` that invokes a method from a superclass on the current instance, so I thought an implementation of this would be create a sketch with the method I already have

```
 class ProcessingRELP extends PApplet{

       public static void main(String[] args) {
            PApplet.main("ProcessingRELP");
       }

       void settings(){

       }

       void setup() {

       }

       void draw() {

       }

       invokeProcessingMethod(String name, Object... args) {
             invokeMethod(name, args);
       }
 }
```

and then do something like

```
 class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            ProcessingRELP sketch = new ProcessingRELP();
            Object data = sketch.invokeProcessingMethod("textWidth", "hello");
       }
 }
```

but I get the following exception because I am not invoking the  Processing method in `setup` or `draw`

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
>       at processing.core.PApplet.textWidth(PApplet.java:12960) 
>       at ProcessingRELP.invokeProcessingMethod(ProcessingRELP.java:27) 
>       at Test.main(Test.java:25)

Is there anyway to invoke a Processing method outside the sketch or a creative way to still do it in the sketch but be able to retrieve the data from outside the sketch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the sketch first, because you are trying to invoke methods that depend on the runtime of the sketch (*textWidth()* uses the *textFont* and *textSize* of a live sketch in its calculation) and not static methods. Simply instantiating a `ProcessingRELP` object will not run it; this can be done with the following:

```
ProcessingRELP sketch = new ProcessingRELP();
PApplet.runSketch(new String[]{"--location=0,0", ""}, sketch);
```

Now you are able to call your method since the sketch is running.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I noticed that if I leave out the command line arguments, it prints out a mesage about the usage of PApplet, and tells me to look at the Javadoc, but when I go there, i cant seem to find info about those arguments. What does `"--location=0, 0",""` do or where can I find info about those arugments?

Comment: @Lindstorm `--location=x,y` specifies the coord of the top-left corner of the sketch's stage. You can find all the available arguments by typing `PApplet.ARGS_` and hopefully your IDE will display them, or see the PApplet class source code on github. As long as there is one argument (can be empty: `new String[]{""}, sketch`), the sketch will run.

Comment: @Lindstorm Oh, and I think the javadoc that the message refers to is the javadoc for the `public static void main(String[] args)` method, where the parameters are explained.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to initialize a Processing sketch in a way that gives you a reference to it. You need to use the `PApplet.main()` function:

```
String[] appletArgs = new String[] { "MySketch" };
PApplet.main("ProcessingRELP");
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java) is a tutorial on using Processing as a Java library.

On top of that, I would be very suspicious of your `invokeMethod()` approach. Why can't you just invoke the function directly?

Something like this:

```
float stringWidth = sketch.textWidth("hello");
```

Either way, I think you're going to need to refactor your code to use the `PApplet.main()` function instead of assuming you have a reference to the sketch itself.

You could do something like move your logic into the `setup()` function of your sketch class. But either way, your Processing sketch needs to be the entry point.